# How many files can I link in the CEWP

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part

I have a CEWP which contains HTML button and JS for functionality. The html editor of the cewp keeps removing certain links from my code and I'd rather just link to the source file. How do I link to a HTML file and JS file separately? Or should I just have one HTML file which  tags?

Comment: Are you actually using a CEWP and not simply the default Rich Text field on a page?  The two behave differently though they look almost identical.  I do this all the time using a CEWP without an issue but trying to do this in the default Rich Text editor always results in what you are describing.

Comment: Not sure, I'm definitely picking Content Editor Web Part, then I'll go into it and select HTML in the ribbon and insert my code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only link one file in the CEWP Link to Source box. You should be able to link to an HTML file that includes links to other resources like JS and CSS files in it.

Comment: Yea that seems like a good solution actually. Thanks!